# how to add token authentication to header

Tags: django, testing

I tried to create a client that uses django test client and make a get request with token authentication. But I get a 401 error so something is wrong ..Of course this also happens for post.
I was looking for different solutions but nothing works.
this is part of the code:

```
from django.test import Client
  class MyClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.token = None

    def get(self, url):
        if self.token is not None:
            new_url = base + url
            result = self.client.get(new_url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization': 'Token {}'.format(self.token)})
        else:
            result = self.client.get(url)
        return result

    def login(self, username, password):
        payload = {
           "username": username,
           "password": password
        }
        response = self.post_without_auth('/api/auth/token_auth/',payload)
        if response.status_code is 200:
           self.token = response.json()['token']
        return response

    def post_without_auth(self, url, payload):
       response = self.client.post(url, payload)
       return response

     def current_user(self):
        response = self.get('/api/current_user/')
        return response
```

Comment: where you are calling the get

Comment: Where do you get `self.post_without_auth` ? And what is the backend code that generates and accepts the token? Are you sure the login gets a `200` response? What are the request and response headers you get when running your code? The code in your question is not complete. We can't understand or verify your problem without more information. [mcve]

Comment: yes, i did some test and it return 200. and i edit my code, in my test i call to current user that call to get after that login happend

Comment: can you mention from where you are calling all these functions

Comment: <code>import logging
from django.test import TestCase
from client import MyClient

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class LoginTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
self.client = MyClient()
        response = self.client.signup("test1@a.com", "passwordTest1","passwordTest1", True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    def test_current_user(self):
        response = self.client.login("test1@a.com", "passwordTest1")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        response = self.client.current_user()

Comment: @Shir13 Please [edit] your question so you can format the code.

Answer (score 1):

call the method post which will set the token value

```
def get(self, url):
    self.post(username, password)
    if self.token is not None:
        new_url = base + url
        result = self.client.get(new_url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization': 'Token {}'.format(self.token)})
    else:
        result = self.client.get(url)
    return result

def login(self, username, password):
    payload = {
       "username": username,
       "password": password
    }
    response = self.post_without_auth('/api/auth/token_auth/',payload)
    if response.status_code is 200:
       self.token = response.json()['token']
    return response
```

Comment: the token is already set after login and i try to use the token just if is not None

Comment: i guess most probably you are using for the test, and may be you are creating the multiple instance of that class.